# IIS ASP.NET 32bit ApplicationPool fails to handle request

Tags: asp.net, iis, 32bit-64bit

I have an application that has a dependency on a 32bit library. When I run it on a 64-bit IIS server I get BadImageFormatException. Changing the application pool settings to "Enable 32-Bit Applications" solves this problem for me.

...until I had to deploy it to my latest environment. When I make a request to the application I get 500 response, not from ASP.NET, probably IIS. Reviewing the %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles shows:

```
sc-status = 500
sc-substatus = 19 (Configuration data is invalid.)
sc-win32-status = 193 (ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT)
```

If I undo "Enable 32-Bit Applications" then I get the usual BadImageFormatException ASP.NET response. So, it looks like IIS is not able to launch the 32-bit application pool host or something... does this make sense? How can I fix or troubleshoot this?

Comment: Keep it as a 32 bit application pool. When you get the 500 error, what do the Windows Event Logs say?

Comment: You have to get the detailed 500.19 error page to learn what's up. FRT should reveal that to you, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: There is nothing in the Event Viewer.
I will enable FRT to see what I get.

Comment: The win32-status code 193 has already show the problem "%1 is not a valid Win32 application.".  There was an compatibility issue. Please ensure the bitness of your dll match the bitness of your application poolhttps://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7. If you are trying to load 64 bit dll in 32 bit app pool, the application always fail.

Answer (score 1):

After enabling Failed Request Tracing I found that the ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT error was caused by StaticCompressionModule and DynamicCompressionModule. I searched some more on the internet and found this [link](https://docs.biztalk360.com/docs/http-error-50019-internal-server-error-with-error-code-0x800700c1).

> Cause of the error
>   With the installation of WSUS (Windows Server Update Services) on the same server, causes a conflicting issue with two new IIS Modules installed at the top level (from WSUS being installed). These modules then propagate down through IIS websites, thus affecting other sites ability to operate, resulting in HTTP Error 500.19 - Error Code 0x800700c1. The two modules in question are locked by default and propagate down within IIS. The Modules added globally are DynamicCompressionModule and StaticCompressionModule.

I recognised that WSUS mentioned by the article was also installed on my environment and I followed their instruction to remove these two modules from the machine configuration. This resolved my issue.

The explanation does not make it clear if these modules were installed by WSUS or if they were overwritten/updated by it. Do I lose anything by removing these modules?